# Migrate to Eclipse 4.3.2 and Remove View Extension

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to migrate from eclipse 3.x to 4.x (the recent one is Kepler SR2).
I have some code like that shown below for removing a view extension.

```java
IExtension extension = Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getExtension("view.id");
IViewRegistry viewRegistry = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getViewRegistry();
((org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ViewRegistry)viewRegistry).removeExtension(extension, new Object[]{view});
```

The removeExtension is no more available in Eclipse Kepler. How can I do that?

Comment: This does not appear to be supported in Kepler. Since ViewRegistry is `internal` you should not have been using it in the first place.

Comment: I know.That is ok. But how can I do the same functionality or behavior now?

Comment: As far as I can see support for removing view extensions has been removed altogether.